# A text editor that would let you execute a Python code snippet against the text

Tags: python, text-editor

Virtually all the text editors let you do search-and-replace, some even support regular expressions, some let you extend their functionality with macros that are quite a job to write and to learn to (you have to study the editor API and often to write the code in a relatively esoteric language).

What I want is an editor that would let you just paste a Python function in a dialogue or a panel the way you paste search and replace samples and run it, passing the entire text edited or selected as a string (or a list of strings) argument to the function and replacing it with what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** is free and cross-platform, it supports this.

- Configure Python engine if you use Linux (see info about option "pylib" in [CudaText Wiki](https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Python_integration))
- call menu Plugins / Make Plugin; confirm to create new plugin
- new plugin created, its `__init__` python file is opened
- change there method `run` like the following:

```
    def run(self):
        ALL_TEXT = False
        if ALL_TEXT:
            s = ed.get_text_all()
            s = '['+s+']' # any function here!!
            ed.set_text_all(s)
            msg_status('all text replaced')
        else:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = ed.get_carets()[0]
            if (y1, x1)>(y2, x2):
                x1,y1,x2,y2 = x2,y2,x1,y1
            if y2<0: return
            s = ed.get_text_substr(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            s = '['+s+']' # any function here!!
            ed.replace(x1, y1, x2, y2, s)
            msg_status('sel replaced')
```

- change ALL_TEXT to use all text or only selection
- call new plugin (restart CudaText) via Plugins / MySample

Comment: Should've probably downvoted this, because it doesn't really answer the question, but I'm upvoting it instead, because that editor seems cool. Took me about 10 minutes to write a useful plugin. And supports font ligatures. And not made with Electron, for a change. Are you the author of CudaText? You seem to be promoting it all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Python script against the entire text by configuring the 'Build' menu selection in the `Geany` editor.  See https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu

This will not allow you to run a script on just a text selection, however.